# SpecFlow wrongly maps identifiers with a number

Tags: unit-testing, specflow

I am implementing testing with SpecFlow and I have this annoying situation: the System name is System33 and whenever I make a reference to the system name, SpecFlow tries to bind "33" as a parameter. For example:

```
Given I am a valid System33 user logged in the system
```

Is bound to this step:

```
[Given(@"I am a valid System(.*) user logged in the system")]
public void GivenIAmAValidSystemUserLoggedInTheSystem(int p0)
```

This is quite anoying because I received the specs from another department and they constantly mention "System33".

I have tried to find a way to override this standard behavior but the documentation is frankly poor.

http://specflow.org/documentation/Using-Gherkin-Language-in-SpecFlow/

Does anybody know a way to tell SpecFlow that a number at the end of a word is NOT a parameter value?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple to explain, your step

```
[Given(@"I am a valid System(.*) user logged in the system")]
```

will result in a Regex that returns a group marked by the `()`. This group is what is passed into the args of your step binding.

However a Regex of

```
"I am a valid (System.*) user logged in the system"
```

will instead return a group with `System33`. You can see this by using a Regex checker, like http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Where a Source of `Given I am a valid System33 user logged in the system` and a Pattern `I am a valid (System.*) user logged in the system`
gives results of

> Result
>
> *Found 1 match:*
>
> 1. `I am a valid System33 user logged in the system` has 1 group:
>
>    1. System33
>
> *String literals for use in programs:*
>
> C#
>
> ```
> @"I am a valid (System.*) user logged in the system"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The code is generated by the skeleton code generator which is part of the Specflow VS Integration. It tries to guess what could be parameters in a step and as most of the time numbers are parameters in steps, we see numbers always as parameters.

You can't configure the behavior of the generator, but change simply the string. This is a regex and can be changed to what you want. The generator generates only a suggestion and starting point for you.